# SMSS18 can't connect to LocalDb

Tags: sql-server, localdb

Something has gone awry from my local machine. Everything used to work fine. Now, I can't connect to `(localdb)\mssqllocaldb`.

Running the application locally from Visual Studio 2022 connects fine. It's using the following connection string:
`"Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=[DatabaseName];Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"`

From SMSS18, I get the following:
[image]

Here's my login screen:
[image]

What am I doing wrong? What can I change to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and this solution worked for me:

[image]

And connect to master database:

[image]

Comment: I gave that a try, but it still doesn't like it.

`A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)`

Comment: Have you try to use ``DatabaseName`` (in connection string) instead of master?